# Help determining a statistical test to use

Tags: r, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I have a data set that has the ages, weights and heights for 444 Olympic athletes. I'm wanting to compare each of these to whether or not that athlete won a medal and see what the correlation is and see what has the biggest impact on winning a medal. My tentative code is below but I'm not sure if this is the right test or if I'm missing something, could somebody give me some guidance? I'm using `medal.f` as a vector of numeric values (0 meaning no medal won, 1 meaning a medal was one) that I changed to a factor to resemble ("No medal", and "medal")

```
wilcox.test(age~medal.f)
wilcox.test(weight~medal.f)
wilcox.test(height~medal.f)
```

Then using these p-values to determine whether to reject or fail to reject the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the Wilcoxon rank-sum test (same as Mann-Whitney-U-test) caters to this situation because your outcome is strictly binomial (1 or 0).  And, this test deals with ranking values and does not deal well with ties.  In this case, you have only two values (two ranks).  So, you will have a bunch of ties and this test essentially breaks down.

You will also run into an issue of multiplicity.  By testing numerous variables on the same data set, you will be much more likely to run into a spurious statistical significance of any of the variables.

Your hypothesis testing problem has several issues.  The first one is quantitative.  I would approach your hypothesis testing differently.  I would use a Logit Regression (also called Logistic Regression).  You could also use a similar Probit Regression.  Either of them would give you similar results and interpretation.  Those regressions essentially would model what is the probability of winning an Olympic model given a specific Age, Weight, and Height.  And, each variable would have their specified statistical significance.  You could also derive their standardized coefficients to determine which one is most influential.

The second set of issues are qualitative.  Different events are driven by completely different combination of Age/Weight/Height factors.  In male weight lifting, athletes need to be heavy and somewhat mature.  In female gymnastics, athletes are truly diminutive on all counts (very young, very short, very light).  Unless your model focuses on either a single discipline or a bucket of disciplines with the exact same Age/Weight/Height requirement profile, your model is not going to make any sense at all.  And, all your variables are likely to be either not statistically significant or potentially have the wrong sign.

Another problem of your hypothesis testing is that none of your variables have a linear relationship with performance (that's what probability of winning a medal represents).  For instance, each sport has a different age-performance curve.  Each sport has a specific age window of just a few years when an athlete is at his peak.  A bit younger or older than that sweetspot window and his probability of winning a medal drops rapidly.  And, for each sport this age-performance curve is different.  In other words, the relationship between age and performance is not linear, it is U shape.  And, the same is true for weight and height.  And, again each sport has different sweetspots for each of those factors.

In view of the above, you will have to transform all three variables so they capture this U shape relationship vs. performance.  Maybe a 2nd degree polynomial would work.  Maybe a trigonometric transformation would too.

As you can tell, your hypothesis testing is a lot more complicated than a straightforward nonparametric unpaired test as you had initially designed the experiment.

The most important thing is whether your data set can be categorized or even split so as to overcome the qualitative issues.

Comment: If the relationship is non-linear and there is a sufficient amount of data, a GAM (or even a GAMM) can be really useful.